# C# Asp.net Web API - creating a JSON/XML converter API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

Just as an exercise I'd like to create an ASP.Net web API which converts between XML and JSON.

this is what I have so far:

[image]

I think the content type checking is right, but I can't test as I am getting "Method not Allowed" when I try and post, is it possible to have routing/binding to achieve my goal?

I am trying to test this with Fiddler:
[image]

my routes look like this:
[image]

my webapi routes look like this: 
[image]
but I still get Method Not Allowed :=/
[image]

Comment: How are you calling this action? Could you show your client code? Also please show your current routes setup.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I've added this info :)

Comment: No, you have shown your MVC routes setup not your Web API routes. Those are 2 completely different things. Also you cannot expect to get the POST request payload into a variable called `jsonOrXml` in your Post action. You will have to read it from the request body. It won't come as parameter. Or if you want it to you will have to write a custom model binder or formatter.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov sorry, where are we webapi routes? how can I load from the request body?

Comment: By default, when you create a new application using the wizard they are placed in `~/App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs`. Also from your Fiddler screenshot I can see that you have provided invalid JSON payload: `{sample:"true"}`. A valid JSON should look like this: `{"sample":"true"}`.

Comment: thanks, I posted the WebAPIConfig and fixed the json, still the same result

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39365/discussion-between-greycloud-and-darin-dimitrov)

Comment: Could you show the response you get from the server in Fiddler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try annotating your action parameter with [FromBodyAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.frombodyattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx). Here's an example:

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
  public string Post([FromBody] string jsonOrXml)
  {
    // Process the input
  }
}
```

In this case the `Content-Type` request header must be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and the body will have the following format: `=[JSON or XML data]`. More details are given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14624306/web-api-parameter-always-null).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, this resolves the Method Not Found error, however the "jsonOrXml" variable is null

Comment: @GreyCloud I've updated my answer (added a helpful link to another SO question).

Comment: thankyou, this looks promising, it means i'd have to wrap any json or xml e.g. {"toconvert": {"sample":"1"}} so that this would match a model in MVC

Comment: i will try this out tomorrow, in the mean time i wonder if it is possible to do this without wrapping?

Comment: @GreyCloud You don't have to wrap anything as long as you use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as content type. Otherwise, you need a model type that you want the POST data (either JSON or XML string) to be mapped to (plus, the correct request type).