# JQuery to Web API: IE9 POST always returns 'Access is Denied'

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, asp.net-web-api, internet-explorer-9

I've got a Web API web service that accepts a POST request.  It works in Chrome, IE10+, but in IE9 it ALWAYS returns 'Error: Access is denied'.  I have already read through [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10232017/ie9-jquery-ajax-with-cors-returns-access-is-denied) several times, and I tried everything suggested in it, but I continue to get the same **access is denied** error.  I just ran Fiddler on the test machine, and when I attempt to make the service call, IE9 isn't even sending out a request, it's just going right to the error block in the code.

Here's the jquery function that makes the call:

```js
function Login (username, password, appId, org, callback) {

    var response = {};

    var loginRequest = {
        Organization: org,
        ApplicationId: appId,
        UserName: username,
        Password: password
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "theurl",
        data: '=' + JSON.stringify(loginRequest),
        success: function (data) {
            response = {
                status: data.status,
                info: data.user
            };
            return callback(response);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            response = {
                status: false,
                info: error.statusText
            };
            return callback(response);
        }
    });

}
```

I know the data looks a little funky, but it's due to a weird Web API issue that [is explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14624306/web-api-parameter-always-null). I just want to reiterate, this function works fine on all other browsers except IE9.  I am already referencing the [jquery.xdomainrequest.js](https://github.com/MoonScript/jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest) file in my html file, but it doesn't solve this issue for me. I've tried specifying the dataType and the contentType in this function, but those cause additional errors.

EDIT: Forgot to mention, this web app is running on a secure (https) port, and the Web API service it is using to login is also running on a secure port, but they are on different machines and different sub-domains (same domain).

I have worked on this for days and I am stumped.  Your help is GREATLY appreciated!